# Data does not get inserted into the table, even though there is no exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying push the data to a database, using JDBC connection. Here is the schema http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06524701188448795628. JDBC connection seems fine as I am getting data from another table properly. And I am getting no exception.

Here is the String

```
String sql = "insert into online_orders_hdr (OOH_ONLINE_REFERENCE_NO, OOH_SERVICE_USER_ID, OOH_ORDER_STATUS," +
                 "OOH_TOTAL_QUANTITY, OOH_TOTAL_AMOUNT, OOH_PAYMENT_MODE, OOH_SHIPPING_ID, OOH_SHIPPING_NAME, OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS1, " +
                  "OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS2, OOH_SHIPPING_PLACE, OOH_SHIPPING_STATE, OOH_SHIPPING_COUNTRY, OOH_SHIPPING_PINCODE, OOH_SHIPPING_MOBILE, "+
                   "OOH_SHIPPING_PHONE, OOH_SHIPPING_EMAIL, OOH_CUSTOMER_ID, OOH_CUSTOMER_NAME, OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1, OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2,"+
                   "OOH_CUSTOMER_CITY, OOH_CUSTOMER_STATE, OOH_CUSTOMER_PINCODE, OOH_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY, OOH_CUSTOMER_MOBILE, OOH_CUSTOMER_EMAIL, "+
                   "OOH_POS_PUSH_STATUS, OOH_CREATED_AT, OOH_UPDATED_AT, OOH_POS_TIMESTAMP, OOH_ONLINE_PUSH_STATUS, OOH_VENDOR) values  "+
                   "("  + OOH_ONLINE_REFERENCE_NO +","+ OOH_SERVICE_USER_ID +","+ OOH_ORDER_STATUS +","+ OOH_TOTAL_QUANTITY +","+ OOH_TOTAL_AMOUNT +","+
                     OOH_PAYMENT_MODE +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_ID +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_NAME +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS1 +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS2 +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_PLACE  +","+
                     OOH_SHIPPING_STATE +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_COUNTRY +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_PINCODE +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_MOBILE +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_PHONE +","+ OOH_SHIPPING_EMAIL  +","+
                   OOH_CUSTOMER_ID+","+ OOH_CUSTOMER_NAME +","+ OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1 +","+ OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2 +","+ OOH_CUSTOMER_CITY +","+ OOH_CUSTOMER_STATE +","+
                   OOH_CUSTOMER_PINCODE+","+ OOH_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY +","+ OOH_CUSTOMER_MOBILE +","+ OOH_CUSTOMER_EMAIL +","+ OOH_POS_PUSH_STATUS +","+ OOH_CREATED_AT +","+ OOH_UPDATED_AT+","+
                   OOH_POS_TIMESTAMP+","+ OOH_ONLINE_PUSH_STATUS +","+ OOH_VENDOR + " )";
```

Here is the SOP of the string

`insert into online_orders_hdr (OOH_ONLINE_REFERENCE_NO, OOH_SERVICE_USER_ID, OOH_ORDER_STATUS,OOH_TOTAL_QUANTITY, OOH_TOTAL_AMOUNT, OOH_PAYMENT_MODE, OOH_SHIPPING_ID, OOH_SHIPPING_NAME, OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS1, OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS2, OOH_SHIPPING_PLACE, OOH_SHIPPING_STATE, OOH_SHIPPING_COUNTRY, OOH_SHIPPING_PINCODE, OOH_SHIPPING_MOBILE, OOH_SHIPPING_PHONE, OOH_SHIPPING_EMAIL, OOH_CUSTOMER_ID, OOH_CUSTOMER_NAME, OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1, OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2,OOH_CUSTOMER_CITY, OOH_CUSTOMER_STATE, OOH_CUSTOMER_PINCODE, OOH_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY, OOH_CUSTOMER_MOBILE, OOH_CUSTOMER_EMAIL, OOH_POS_PUSH_STATUS, OOH_CREATED_AT, OOH_UPDATED_AT, OOH_POS_TIMESTAMP, OOH_ONLINE_PUSH_STATUS, OOH_VENDOR) values  (1262571076,123,pending,1,250.0,COD,11111,22222,sarathy nagar, Velachery,,Chennai,Tamil Nadu,India,600042,7639817688,null,gvpmahesh@gmail.com,33333,Vamsi g,sarathy nagar, Velachery,,Chennai,Tamil Nadu,600042,India,7639817688,gvpmahesh@gmail.com,pending,2015-08-21 06:12:47,2015-08-21 06:13:11,2000-01-01 12:00:00,0,SHOPIFY )`

I am using `statement.executeUpdate(sql) for execution`. // sql String I mentioned above
Here is the logger output

`9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_ONLINE_REFERENCE_NO -- 1262571076
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SERVICE_USER_ID -- 123
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_ORDER_STATUS -- pending
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_TOTAL_QUANTITY --  1
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_TOTAL_AMOUNT -- 250.0
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_PAYMENT_MODE -- COD
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_ID -- 11111
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_NAME -- 22222
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS1 -- sarathy nagar, Velachery
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
WARNING: The shipping address2 can fail
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS2-- 
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_PLACE -- Chennai
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_STATE -- Tamil Nadu
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_COUNTRY -- India
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_PINCODE -- 600042
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_MOBILE -- 7639817688
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
WARNING: This can fail
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_PHONE -- null
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_SHIPPING_EMAIL -- gvpmahesh@gmail.com
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_ID -- 33333
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_NAME --Vamsi g
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1 -- sarathy nagar, Velachery
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
WARNING: This may fail
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2 -- 
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_CITY -- Chennai
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_STATE -- Tamil Nadu
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_PINCODE -- 600042
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY -- India
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_MOBILE -- 7639817688
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_CUSTOMER_EMAIL -- gvpmahesh@gmail.com
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_POS_PUSH_STATUS -- pending
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
SEVERE: OOH_CREATED_AT -- 2015-08-21 06:12:47
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
SEVERE: OOH_UPDATED_AT -- 2015-08-21 06:13:11
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
SEVERE: OOH_POS_TIMESTAMP -- 2000-01-01 12:00:00
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_ONLINE_PUSH_STATUS -- 0
9 Sep, 2015 5:26:53 PM Hello getOrders
INFO: OOH_VENDOR -- SHOPIFY`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you missing quotes in the values section of your sql?

Comment: I just printed the sql query to see what is in there. Check the string sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of string concatenation:

```
// create the string with the insert statement
String sqlInsertString = "insert into online_orders_hdr ( " +
    " OOH_ONLINE_REFERENCE_NO, OOH_SERVICE_USER_ID, OOH_ORDER_STATUS, " +
    " OOH_TOTAL_QUANTITY, OOH_TOTAL_AMOUNT, OOH_PAYMENT_MODE, " +
    " OOH_SHIPPING_ID, OOH_SHIPPING_NAME, OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS1, " +
    " OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS2, OOH_SHIPPING_PLACE, OOH_SHIPPING_STATE, " + 
    " OOH_SHIPPING_COUNTRY, OOH_SHIPPING_PINCODE, OOH_SHIPPING_MOBILE, " + 
    " OOH_SHIPPING_PHONE, OOH_SHIPPING_EMAIL, OOH_CUSTOMER_ID, " +
    " OOH_CUSTOMER_NAME, OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1, " + 
    " OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2, OOH_CUSTOMER_CITY, OOH_CUSTOMER_STATE, " + 
    " OOH_CUSTOMER_PINCODE, OOH_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY, OOH_CUSTOMER_MOBILE, " +
    " OOH_CUSTOMER_EMAIL, OOH_POS_PUSH_STATUS, OOH_CREATED_AT, " + 
    " OOH_UPDATED_AT, OOH_POS_TIMESTAMP, OOH_ONLINE_PUSH_STATUS, " +
    " OOH_VENDOR) values  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

// prepare the statement
PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(sqlInsertString);

// populate the statement variables
int i = 0;
insert.setString(++i, OOH_ONLINE_REFERENCE_NO);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SERVICE_USER_ID);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_ORDER_STATUS);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_TOTAL_QUANTITY);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_TOTAL_AMOUNT);            
insert.setString(++i, OOH_PAYMENT_MODE);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_ID);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_NAME);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS1);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS2);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_PLACE);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_STATE);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_COUNTRY);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_PINCODE);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_MOBILE);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_PHONE);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_SHIPPING_EMAIL);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_ID);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_NAME);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_CITY);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_STATE);                
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_PINCODE);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_MOBILE);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CUSTOMER_EMAIL);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_POS_PUSH_STATUS);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_CREATED_AT);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_UPDATED_AT);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_POS_TIMESTAMP);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_ONLINE_PUSH_STATUS);
insert.setString(++i, OOH_VENDOR);

// execute the insert statement
insert.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();
```

Of course you have to use the appropriate `set...`-methods on the PreparedStatement that match the parameter's type.

Comment: Mine is standalone application, which runs on Desktop. It can be started by command line only, so I don't think it's vulnerable.  But still it's a nice suggestion. And BTW, did you find anything wrong in my code?

Comment: You should **never** use string concatenation to add parameters to an SQL statement. Your application IS vulnerable, even it does not seem that an attacker will choose it as an attack vector.

Comment: In your code, you seem to produce problems with at least some missing quotes and also the timestamp fields. Use prepared statements to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

try setting your autocommit to true on the connection:

```
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Comment: Still I am getting empty result set.